# Is Python *with* statement exactly equivalent to a try - (except) - finally block?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I know this was widely discussed, but I still can't find an answer to confirm this: is the *with* statement identical to calling the same code in a try - (except) -finally block, where whatever one defines in the `__exit__` function of the context manager is placed in the finally block?

For example -- are these 2 code snippets doing exactly the same thing?

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def open_input(fpath):
    fd = open(fpath) if fpath else sys.stdin
    try:
        yield fd
    finally:
        fd.close()

with open_input("/path/to/file"):
    print "starting to read from file..."
```

the same as:

```
def open_input(fpath):
    try:
        fd = open(fpath) if fpath else sys.stdin
        print "starting to read from file..."
    finally:
        fd.close()

open_input("/path/to/file")
```

Thanks!

Comment: you would get two different errors, the context manager would give an io error on an invalid path and the `try/finally` would give a `referenced before assignment` error

Comment: Also what is the `__exit__` function in your code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The context manager uses the generator (function with yield) to create the `__enter__` and `__exit__` blocks.

Comment: @Dunes, I understand how context managers work, I was asking the OP what they considered the exit function

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'm going to put aside mentions of scope, because it's really not very relevant.

According to [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/),

```
with EXPR as VAR:
    BLOCK
```

translates to

```
mgr = (EXPR)
exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

As you can see, `type(mgr).__enter__` is called as you expect, but **not inside the `try`**.

`type(mgr).__exit__` is called on exit. The only difference is that **when there is an exception, the `if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info())` path is taken**. This gives `with` the ability to introspect and silence errors unlike what a `finally` clause can do.

---

`contextmanager` doesn't complicate this *much*. It's just:

```
def contextmanager(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def helper(*args, **kwds):
        return _GeneratorContextManager(func, *args, **kwds)
    return helper
```

Then look at the class in question:

```
class _GeneratorContextManager(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwds):
        self.gen = func(*args, **kwds)

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            return next(self.gen)
        except StopIteration:
            raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if type is None:
            try:
                next(self.gen)
            except StopIteration:
                return
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
        else:
            if value is None:
                value = type()
            try:
                self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
                raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
            except StopIteration as exc:
                return exc is not value
            except:
                if sys.exc_info()[1] is not value:
                    raise
```

Unimportant code has been elided.

The first thing to note is that if there are multiple `yield`s, this code will error.

This does not affect the control flow noticeably.

Consider `__enter__`.

```
try:
    return next(self.gen)
except StopIteration:
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
```

If the context manager was well written, this will never break from what is expected.

**One difference is that if the generator throws `StopIteration`, a different error (`RuntimeError`) will be produced.** This means the behaviour is not totally identical to a normal `with` if you're running completely arbitrary code.

Consider a non-erroring `__exit__`:

```
if type is None:
    try:
        next(self.gen)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
```

The only difference is as before; if your code throws `StopIteration`, it will affect the generator and thus the `contextmanager` decorator will misinterpret it.

This means that:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def with_cleanup(func):
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        func()

def good_cleanup():
    print("cleaning")

with with_cleanup(good_cleanup):
    print("doing")
    1/0
#>>> doing
#>>> cleaning
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 15, in <module>
#>>> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

def bad_cleanup():
    print("cleaning")
    raise StopIteration

with with_cleanup(bad_cleanup):
    print("doing")
    1/0
#>>> doing
#>>> cleaning
```

Which is unlikely to matter, but it could.

Finally:

```
else:
    if value is None:
        value = type()
    try:
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
    except StopIteration as exc:
        return exc is not value
    except:
        if sys.exc_info()[1] is not value:
            raise
```

This raises the same question about `StopIteration`, but it's interesting to note that last part.

```
if sys.exc_info()[1] is not value:
    raise
```

This means that if the exception is unhandled, the traceback will be unchanged. If it was handled but a *new* traceback exists, that will be raised instead.

This perfectly matches the spec.

---

#### TL;DR

- `with` is actually slightly more powerful than a `try...finally` in that the `with` can introspect and silence errors.
- Be careful about `StopIteration`, but otherwise you're fine using `@contextmanager` to create context managers.

Comment: Is the nested `try` required? Is it equivalent to use `except: if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()): raise    else: exit(mgr, None, None, None)`?

Also, why do `exit = type(mgr).__exit__` instead of just `exit = mgr.__exit__`? The prior seems oddly specific. That said, it does seem to be what `with` uses: If you do `foo.__enter__ = lambda 'asdf'` and then do `with foo as x: print x`, it doesn't use `'asdf'`.

Comment: @Ben I think you're right that the `try` doesn't need to be nested, but you do need a `finally` nonetheless. `exit = type(mgr).__exit__` is used because CPython has a history of caching special methods and this just makes it consistent.

Comment: Wouldn't the `finally` behavior be covered by the `else` portion of `try`/`except`/`else`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see. Glad I asked :-)

Comment: A very nicely written article that highlights slight differences (that rarely manifest) between these can also be found [here](https://vorpus.org/blog/control-c-handling-in-python-and-trio/#id5) for those interested.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the `finally` question, I was wondering the exact same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59322585/2326961

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, it helps! However why the outer `try` statement? Couldn’t you just put the `finally` clause in the inner `try` statement?

Comment: @Veedrac Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59344104/2326961