# Why the staggering overhead [50X] of contextlib and the With statement in Python and what to do about it

Tags: python, with-statement

In the process of hunting down performance bugs I finally identified that the source of the problem is the contextlib wrapper. The overhead is quite staggering and I did not expect that to be the source of the slowdown. The slowdown is in the range of 50X, I cannot afford to have that in a loop. I sure would have appreciated a warning in the docs if it has the potential of slowing things down so significantly.

It seems this has been known since 2010 https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/736778

It has a set of benchmarks you can try. Please change `fn` to `fn()` in `simple_catch()` before running. Thanks, DSM for pointing this out.

I am surprised that the situation has not improved since those times. What can I do about it? I can drop down to try/except, but I hope there are other ways to deal with it.

Comment: I don't know if your statement is true, but Python community is generally not that interested in performance.

Comment: @SiyuanRen "I don't know if your statement is true" that is the reason why I linked the benchmarking code. Its very easy to run.

Comment: I ran it, and it seems to validate your point. But a lot of times the problems are with the benchmarking rather than the actual system, which I see in supposed 'C++ is too slow on this and that' too many times. I'm not that well versed in Python to tell in this one.

Comment: There's a major bug in that benchmark -- if you look at the `simple_catch` function, it doesn't actually *call* `fn`, it simply names it.  That's why the two `simple_catch` results are effectively identical.  (This is only a comment, not an answer, because it's still true that the contextlib approach is slower, although it's not nearly as big a deal when the function being called actually *does* something.)

Comment: @DSM Shoot should have mentioned that I had caught (no pun intended)  and fixed that.  My larger point remains, simple_catch(work_pass) is still about 50x slower than with_catch(work_fail). Its very possible that I am missing something, such a big overhead is unlikely to have gone unnoticed.

Comment: From the earliest days we were encouraged to use `try:except:`, often in preference to `if test:do`.  So it was coded for minimal speed penalty.  `contextlib` is pure Python, without any compiled speedups.

Comment: @hpaulj Given contextlib's (and with's) utility any speed improvement would certainly be appreciated. If that means coding it as a C module, so be it.

Comment: @san I ran this on pypy and interestingly it showed the same problem.

Comment: @simonzack Thanks for letting me know. Was wondering about it myself, that is, whether PyPy can optimize the overhead away. May be it can once it hits `context` often in its codepath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some new timings:

```
import contextlib
import timeit

def work_pass():
    pass

def work_fail():
    1/0

def simple_catch(fn):
    try:
        fn()
    except Exception:
        pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def catch_context():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception:
        pass

def with_catch(fn):
    with catch_context():
        fn()

class ManualCatchContext(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return True

def manual_with_catch(fn):
    with ManualCatchContext():
        fn()

preinstantiated_manual_catch_context = ManualCatchContext() 
def manual_with_catch_cache(fn):
    with preinstantiated_manual_catch_context:
        fn()

setup = 'from __main__ import simple_catch, work_pass, work_fail, with_catch, manual_with_catch, manual_with_catch_cache'
commands = [
    'simple_catch(work_pass)',
    'simple_catch(work_fail)',
    'with_catch(work_pass)',
    'with_catch(work_fail)',
    'manual_with_catch(work_pass)',
    'manual_with_catch(work_fail)',
    'manual_with_catch_cache(work_pass)',
    'manual_with_catch_cache(work_fail)',
    ]
for c in commands:
    print c, ': ', timeit.timeit(c, setup)
```

I've made `simple_catch` *actually call the function* and I've added two new benchmarks.

Here's what I got:

```
>>> python2 bench.py
simple_catch(work_pass) :  0.413918972015
simple_catch(work_fail) :  3.16218209267
with_catch(work_pass) :  6.88726496696
with_catch(work_fail) :  11.8109841347
manual_with_catch(work_pass) :  1.60508012772
manual_with_catch(work_fail) :  4.03651213646
manual_with_catch_cache(work_pass) :  1.32663416862
manual_with_catch_cache(work_fail) :  3.82525682449
python2 p.py.py  33.06s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 33.099 total
```

And for PyPy:

```
>>> pypy bench.py
simple_catch(work_pass) :  0.0104489326477
simple_catch(work_fail) :  0.0212869644165
with_catch(work_pass) :  0.362847089767
with_catch(work_fail) :  0.400238037109
manual_with_catch(work_pass) :  0.0223228931427
manual_with_catch(work_fail) :  0.0208241939545
manual_with_catch_cache(work_pass) :  0.0138869285583
manual_with_catch_cache(work_fail) :  0.0213649272919
```

The overhead is much smaller than you claimed. Further, the only overhead PyPy doesn't seem to be able to remove relative to the `try`...`catch` for the manual variant is object creation, which is trivially removed in this case.

---

Unfortunately [`with` is *way* too involved for good optimization by CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26096914/1763356), especially with regards to `contextlib` which even PyPy finds hard to optimize. This is normally OK because although object creation + a function call + creating a generator is expensive, it's *cheap* compared to what is normally done.

If you are *sure* that `with` is causing most of your overhead, convert the context managers into cached instances like I have. If that's still too much overhead, you've likely got a bigger problem with how your system is designed. Consider making the scope of the `with`s bigger (not normally a good idea, but acceptable if need be).

---

Also, PyPy. Dat JIT be *fast*.

Comment: Glad to see that PyPy optimizes the overhead away. Caching is indeed a good idea, thanks ! I am on a much slower machine and 32 bit too, that might explain the difference in the amount of overhead perceived.