# With assignment expressions in Python 3.8, why do we need to use `as` in `with`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

Now that [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) has been accepted, Python 3.8 is destined to have *assignment expressions*, so we can use an assignment expression in `with`, i.e.

```
with (f := open('file.txt')):
    for l in f:
        print(f)
```

instead of

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        print(f)
```

and it would work as before.

What use does the `as` keyword have with the `with` statement in Python 3.8? Isn't this against the Zen of Python: *"There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it."*?

---

When the feature was originally proposed, it wasn't clearly specified whether the assignment expression should be parenthesized in `with` and that

```
with f := open('file.txt'):
    for l in f:
        print(f)
```

could work. However, in Python 3.8a0,

```
with f := open('file.txt'):
    for l in f:
        print(f)
```

will cause

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    with f := open('file.txt'):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but the parenthesized expression works.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The behaviour is not the same for both constructs, even though there wouldn't be discernible differences between the 2 examples.

You should almost never need `:=` in a `with` statement, and sometimes it is very wrong. When in doubt, always use `with ... as ...` when you need the managed object within the `with` block.

---

In `with context_manager as managed`, `managed` is bound to the *return value* of `context_manager.__enter__()`, whereas in `with (managed := context_manager)`, `managed` is bound to the `context_manager` itself and the return value of the `__enter__()` method call is *discarded*. The behaviour is *almost* identical for open files, because their `__enter__` method returns `self`.

The first excerpt is [*roughly* analogous to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096435/is-python-with-statement-exactly-equivalent-to-a-try-except-finally-bloc)

```
_mgr = (f := open('file.txt')) # `f` is assigned here, even if `__enter__` fails
_mgr.__enter__()               # the return value is discarded

exc = True
try:
    try:
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not _mgr.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        _mgr.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

whereas the `as` form would be

```
_mgr = open('file.txt')   # 
_value = _mgr.__enter__() # the return value is kept

exc = True
try:
    try:
        f = _value        # here f is bound to the return value of __enter__
                          # and therefore only when __enter__ succeeded
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not _mgr.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        _mgr.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

i.e. `with (f := open(...))` would set `f` to the return value of `open`, whereas `with open(...) as f` binds `f` to the return value of the *implicit* `__enter__()` method call.

Now, in case of **files and streams**, `file.__enter__()` will return `self` if it succeeds, so the behaviour for these two approaches is *almost* the same - the only difference is in the event that `__enter__` throws an exception.

The fact that assignment expressions will often work instead of `as` is deceptive, because there are many classes where `_mgr.__enter__()` returns an object that is *distinct* from `self`. In that case an assignment expression works differently: the context manager is assigned, instead of the *managed object*. For example [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) is a context manager that will return the *mock* object. The documentation for it has the following example:

```
>>> thing = object()
>>> with patch('__main__.thing', new_callable=NonCallableMock) as mock_thing:
...     assert thing is mock_thing
...     thing()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: 'NonCallableMock' object is not callable
```

Now, if it were to be written to use an assignment expression, the behaviour would be different:

```
>>> thing = object()
>>> with (mock_thing := patch('__main__.thing', new_callable=NonCallableMock)):
...     assert thing is mock_thing
...     thing()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AssertionError
>>> thing
<object object at 0x7f4aeb1ab1a0>
>>> mock_thing
<unittest.mock._patch object at 0x7f4ae910eeb8>
```

`mock_thing` is now bound to the context manager instead of the new mock object.