# What is the equivalent try statement of the with statement?

Tags: python, try-catch, with-statement

After reading the [`with` statement section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) of the language documentation of Python, I was wondering if it is correct to state that this Python code:

```
with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
    SUITE
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
try:
    manager = (EXPRESSION)
    value = manager.__enter__()
    TARGET = value  # only if `as TARGET` is present in the with statement
    SUITE
except:
    import sys
    if not manager.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
        raise
else:
    manager.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

## Edit

The correct equivalent Python code (the real CPython implementation is in C) was actually given by Guido van Rossum himself in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement):

```
mgr = (EXPR)
exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

Since Python 3.6, this has changed a little: now the `__enter__` function is loaded *before* the `__exit__` function (cf. https://bugs.python.org/issue27100).

So my equivalent Python code had three flaws:

1. The `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions should be loaded before calling the `__enter__` function.
2. The `__enter__` function should be called outside the `try` statement (cf. the note of point 4 in the language documentation).
3. The `else` clause should instead be a `finally` clause, to handle the case when there is a non-local goto statement (`break`, `continue`, `return`) in `suite`.

**However I don’t understand why the equivalent Python code in PEP 343 puts the `finally` clause in an outer `try` statement instead of in the inner `try` statement?**

Comment: No, the context closing will always happen, not only in case of an exception. Therefore I see no significant overlap between these constructs.

Comment: The docs you link to explicitly mention `finally`, they're not equivalent at the minute since exit will not be performed unless there's an error

Comment: @guidot Good catch, I forgot to include the case where there is no exception. Let me update the question.

Comment: To put it as plainly as possible, `with` is similar to `try\except\finally` but not `try\except`.

Comment: @Sayse Then could you provide an answer using `finally`?

Comment: @maestro.inc Then could you provide an answer using `finally`?

Comment: [*"`with` is actually slightly more powerful than a `try...finally` in that the with can introspect and silence errors."*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26096914/476)

Comment: `try: \n f = open('file.txt', 'r') \n\r except Exception: print('error working on file') \n\r finally: f.close()`

Comment: @maestro.inc I meant a general answer, not a particular example.

Comment: @Sayse I have updated my question. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick Coghlan, the other author of [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), answered on the [Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue39037):

> It's a matter of historical timing: PEP 343 was written before
>   try/except/finally was allowed, when try/finally and try/except were
>   still distinct statements.
>
> However, PEP 341 was *also* accepted and implemented for Python 2.5,
>   allowing for the modern try/except/finally form:
>   https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-341-unified-try-except-finally

So the modern `try` statement equivalent Python code of the `with` statement is this one:

```
manager = (EXPRESSION)
enter = type(manager).__enter__
exit = type(manager).__exit__
value = enter(manager)
hit_except = False

try:
    TARGET = value  # only if `as TARGET` is present in the with statement
    SUITE
except:
    import sys
    hit_except = True
    if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
finally:
    if not hit_except:
        exit(manager, None, None, None)
```

Comment: And thanks to @Maggyero's PR, this expansion will now appear in the main CPython documentation: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/226e6e7d4326cf91ef37e13528eb1f62de1bb832 :)